# Display javascript values in gravity forms?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to use javascript in a html field using gravity forms and but I can't seem to figure out how to display the value in a different field.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery( '#input_1_2' ).val( 'boom' );
```

Where "1" is the form ID and "2" is the field ID you want to populate.